# suitescript 2.0:When I use removeSelectOption,throw a 'TypeError Cannot read property "removeSelectOption" of null' error

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

There is a js error When I use the removeSelectOption to remove all of the dropdown list.The code as follow:

```
function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {
    if(scriptContext.fieldId == 'class'){
        var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        var brand_id = currentRecord.getValue({fieldId:'class'});
        if(brand_id){
            var itemList = [];
            var itemField = currentRecord.getField({
                fieldId: 'item'
            });
            itemField.removeSelectOption({
                value: null,
            });
            search.create({
                type: search.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
                columns:[{name:'internalid'}],
                filters:[
                    ['custitem30',search.Operator.ANYOF,brand_id]
                ]
            }).run().each(function(result){
                item_id = result.getValue({
                    name:'internalid'
                });
                var in_item = record.load({
                    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
                    id: item_id,
                });
                itemList.push(item_id);
                itemField.insertSelectOption({
                    value: item_id,
                    text: in_item
                });
                console.log('item_id:' + item_id);
            });
            console.log('itemList:' + itemList);
        }
    }
}
```

And the api document in help center said -- To remove all options from the list, set this field to null, as follows:

```
field.removeSelectOption({
value: null,
});
```

If I want to remove all options from the dropdown list,what should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1. Create a item saved search 
   2.Transaction form Item Filter field select that Saved Search.

As your question i assumed that you only show inventory item in item Field.

Comment: But my search filter is dynamic.Before the sales order record is saved,my item dropdown list will be changed when the value of brand field is changed.

Comment: item is not an normal select field it is a sub record field. So We can't remove selection as well as addselection option.

Comment: Oh,I see. Field.removeSelectOption is supported only on fields whose fieldIds have a prefix of custpage.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have get the field object

```
var field = currentRecord.getField({
    fieldId: 'Your Field ID'
});
```

then use this below code

```
field.removeSelectOption({
value: null,
});
```

Comment: Maybe my description is not accurate enough.I have modified the question and post all of the code about the function.I have got the field object before using removeSelectOption.

Comment: I think you  are working on Sales order record right.

Comment: Yes.I want to remove all of the item dropdown list.And then,insert the search result into the dropdown list.

Comment: You only load Inventory Item alone right in suite script that's not possible. you can  use another way to filter items.

Comment: Customize your transaction form go to sublist field tab

Comment: Refer below answer i think it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot remove the field items from the list that are created from UI and have a source.
you can have a alert for it on field change